# JPEG - RTP - Type and qFactor

Tags: jpeg, rtp

I am trying to figure out which JPEG data the RTP header needs for the two header fields "type" and "Q" http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2435.txt

I don't understand where in the JPEG File I can find this information?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My] an implementation of the request for comments which is relevant [2435] may be found at http://net7mma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#RtspServer/MediaTypes/RFC2435Media.cs et al.

Additionally the Type comes from determining if the Jpeg is Progressive or not as well as the sub sampling (4:2:0 / 4:2:1) and the Quality must be known in advance or estimated from the obtained Q[uantization]Tables, specifying Q = 100 and using the Q[sic]Tables from the JPEG is also valid but uses more bandwidth.